# Choosing a district by city problem with php

Tags: javascript, php

I try to make when you select the city, show the district of this city. I am adding my code to below. I made it on local and it has not any issue but whenever  I add this on online it's show noting. It consists of 3 parts; First part is input area, second part is Javascript area and last part for connect to database and get date.
here's input area:

```
<form action="#institutions" method="post">
          <p>Select City*</p>
<select class="institutionsSelect" name="cityinstitutions" id="orders-institutions" onchange="getDetaiinstitutions(this.value);">
    
</select>

<p>Select District </p>
<select class="institutionsSelect" name="districtinstitutions" id="order-details-institutions">
    
</select> <br>
<input type="submit" name="institutionsList" autocomplete="off" value="LİST OF INSTITUTIONS" class="btn btn-md btn-blue black-hover" >

      </form>
```

Here's javascript area;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getOrdersinstitutions() {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("GET", "get-orders-institutions.php", true);
    ajax.send();

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var html = "<option>Select City</option>";
            for (var a = 0; a < response.length; a++) {
                html += "<option value='" + response[a].cityId + "'>";
                    html += response[a].cityName;
                html += "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("orders-institutions").innerHTML = html;
        }
    };
}

function getDetailinstitutions(cityId) {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("GET", "get-order-detail-institutions.php?cityId=" + cityId, true);
    ajax.send();

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var html = "<option></option>";
            for (var a = 0; a < response.length; a++) {
                html += "<option value='" + response[a].districtId + "'>";
                    html += response[a].districtName;
                html += "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("order-details-institutions").innerHTML = html;
        }
    };
}



getOrdersinstitutions();
```

And here's is datebase connection areas. There are 2 different page one call get-orders-institutions.php and other is get-order-detail-institutions.php

**get-orders-institutions.php **

```
  <?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "userName", "password", "ys_table");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ys_city";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    array_push($data, $row);

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

and **get-order-detail-institutions.php**

```
    <?php

$cityId = $_GET["cityId"];
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "userName", "password", "ys_table");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ys_district WHERE cityId='$cityId'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    array_push($data, $row);

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Here all i used codes.
As the first option, select city should be written, but it is an empty input line. Whenever i change datebase setting i mean when i write wrong username and password Select City appear.
By the way these codes work fine in local with exactly the same codes with the same database.
Here is online page
[online input area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgxkd.png)

here is local
[Local input area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DYkB.png)
[Local input result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FXvv.png)

What i suppose to do for take same result in online like local?
thanks in advance

UPDATE: I find what's the problem but i dont know how can i fix it.
If more than 16 rows of data are loaded into the ys_city table, it gives an error like this
How can i fix it?

Comment: $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "userName", "password", "ys_table");

hope this is not same with your server

Comment: no its not same i just change it for here

Comment: did you had chance to checkout error.logs in the server ? / when something is not working similarly in elsewhere it's good to check errors

Comment: Is the missing `l` in your first `onChange` just a typo on this forum? Do you get any errors on the console log in your browser?

Comment: @droopsnoot is forgot to l in there but for forum, there is writen true in real code.

Comment: when I checkout error.logs I didnt find any error for this. I dont understand what's wrong on code. cant find anything even in error.log

Comment: And nothing in the browser console? If you call either of the PHP scripts from the browser directly with an appropriate parameter set, do they work as you expect?

Comment: @droopsnoot in the browser console its appear for this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ajax.onreadystatechange ((index):1801) i guess i need some research for this i find error code

Comment: Ok, that suggests that what is coming back from the PHP is not correctly formed. So, can you run the PHP directly and see what happens? That might show you some PHP errors, especially if you enable error reporting, or check for errors in your code.

Comment: @droopsnoot sorry i dont understand what do you mean what am i suppose to do? i figure out whats wrong actually.I use ut8_unicode on database and tables beacause i use turkish alphabet and if i use 'ö' in any word suddenly broke. I can use it without 'ö' or 'ü', it's gave me what i want but i have to use 'ö' and 'ü'.

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't know anything about character sets but I'm sure it's possible to sort it out. That does make sense, though - perhaps your local server has different default character sets than the one you've now uploaded to.

Comment: @droopsnoot i guess its about json_encode its cant take date with speacial characters. Now i'am searching for this eventually its gonna sort it out. Thank you for everything